# Error in using >> operator

Tags: c++

I'm using a >> operator to input objects on class. I don't know why doesn't work.

I've already included  on library.h

The error displayed is:

> Error 1   error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
istream & operator >> (istream &in,PhanSo &A)
{
    cout << endl << "Nhap phan so: " << endl << "Nhap tu: ";
    in >> A.tu;
    cout << endl << "Nhap mau: ";
    in >> A.mau;
    return in;
}
```

http://codepad.org/KbKhdAV4

Comment: And what is library.h?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing to include the headers in your program. Try to include the headers like `<string>`, `<istream>`,`<iostream>`